# VTK and ITK for C++

Tags: c++, vtk, itk

I'm very new to using libraries for C++ and I have some doubts. I will need to work with medical images, MRI in particular, (DICOM format). I want to process those images - get the particular pixel values. However, as I read, I need some additional libraries to be able to work with DICOM file format in C++. I found VTK and ITK *libraries*. However, I'm not sure if it is libraries for c++... Does anyone know? DO I only need to download it, install and use it in my C++ code or is it a separate tool with GUI? Will I be able to read DICOM file formats and access its pixel values and manipulate it with C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTK and ITK are both open source C++ libraries.

I think the confusion might come from the [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) file source formats which can be vizualize by a GUI interface [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/).

Kitwares propose several tools in medical imaging, data vizualization, which can be used "together" hence the confusion. 
But you can consider VTK and ITK as C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

ITK and VTK are libraries written in C++, so you can download the code, compile the libraries and link them with your C++ code.  ITK supports reading and writing DICOM files, along with a host of there medical image formats.  You will be able to access pixel values in your C++ code using ITK.

Answer (score 0):

ITK and VTK are written in C ++.
But if you want somenter read DICOM files, recomento use only VTK.
VTK is responsible for data representation as part ITK will treat filter handling.

vtkDICOMImageReader is the recommended class for reading DICOM files (.dcm or .dir)

If you choose to use VTK and ITK, will have to activate the function itkvtkglue